# Writing a wrapper to malloc with void as return type

Tags: c

I have a requirement to write a wrapper to `malloc` with return type as void . the exact signature of the function would be

```
void mymalloc_wrapper(size_t size).
```

Any suggestion as to how this can be achieved/is it possible at all ?.

Comment: if this wrapper only returns void than what good is it from the first place?

Comment: Why i want to return nothing (void) ?! So you want simply allocate memory  ?

Comment: Someone is asking you to implement `malloc` in a way, that it can only create memory leaks? Rationale, please.

Comment: Maybe instead that signature you could have void mymalloc_wrapper(size_t size, void ** ptr); In that case, you would be able to put the pointer itself to NULL in case something went wrong.

Comment: Exactly, malloc is just 'void *malloc(size_t size);'. So if you really dislike the pointer you'd just have 'void mymalloc_wrapper(size_t size){malloc(size);}', though I can't imagine any usage of such "wrapper".

Comment: Maybe you misread and you were actually asked to return `void *` ?

Answer (score 3):

With your signature, the only thing you can do is:

```
void mymalloc_wrapper(size_t size) {
    malloc(size);
}
```

Wonderful, you have allocated memory and you have lost the pointer to it. *That's not a good idea*.

If you want a `void` function, you can pass a pointer to return the pointer to allocated memory:

```
void mymalloc_wrapper(size_t size, void** ptr) {
    *ptr = malloc(size);
}
```